# Discovered a vertical hole drilled in what I assume is a structural support beam

Tags: structural

Want to remove two small 'wing walls' that I know were not original construction (from the plans). Simple job I think, until I remove the drywall and reveal someone drilled a vertical hole to route electrics through what I assume is a structural beam.

Now my concern is that the 2x4 stud is potentially carrying vertical load and removing the that will potentially lead to collapse.

I presume the answer is get a structural engineer's opinion, but I'm curious what others think.

[image]

Edit: Some more info, the span that I can measure is 185 inches, the beam is 3.5 inches wide and 9 inches high.

The whole in the plate is 1.5 inches and it appears that the hole in the beam is smaller (1 inch) and offset to indicate they were drilled at different times.

Comment: More pics - https://postimg.cc/gallery/9XBZjyf

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the additional images. Also, it's strongly preferred to use the site's default image hosting partner (as you did with the first one you posted).

Comment: Diameter of the hole (in the beam, if beam and plate have holes of different sizes) and width of beam?

Comment: The hole doesn't concern me but it's possible the beam was sized with the wing wall in consideration.  In fact that seems likely, why else would that little wall be there?  OTOH you'd expect more than a 2x4 at the end of a wall doing that job.  So ..... ya, engineer time.

Comment: @jay613 Question states that the wing walls are not in the original plans.

Comment: @Ecnerwal oops I missed that.  So ya I guess the question for the engineer is, is the additional support of the wall required to compensate for the hole?  And oh DOES it compensate for the hole?

Comment: Added some edits. To Jays point the wing wall I highlighting was NOT in the original plan, however the other wing wall along side the oven was.

Comment: IDK because there's still drywall between you, me, and what this beam is. *Finish the demo*. Structural engineers can't see though gypsum either.

Comment: If it's an actual 4x beam with a one inch hole *down the absolute center* then it's ... probably... fine?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/182693/can-i-drill-vertically-through-this-from-the-main-floor-to-the-upstairs - **something about the hole not being larger than 1/3 of the width of the member**. Related : https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/194096/what-structure-is-inside-these-stair-walls-between-floors-for-running-wire/194108#194108 - which would make a 1" hole in a 3.5" member okay.... but I failed to cite any code.

Comment: This one says *don't*... if you want that to be the answer. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29035/is-it-ok-to-drill-vertically-through-a-joist

Answer (score 2):

Based on the updated question and comments:  If there are two of these walls, one of them was in the original plans, and you want to remove both you need a structural engineer to determine if the beam is sized for the entire span without either wall, and if it can meet that demand with the hole.